# Store file with Mongoose/GridFS with FeathersJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs, feathersjs, gridfs-stream

Building a REST API with FeathersJS I need to be able to upload a picture (POST), record if thanks to GridFS and be able GET it later.

I start set up GridFS with Mongoose:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
Grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;

module.exports = function () {
  const app = this;

  mongoose.connect(app.get('mongodb'));
  const cnx = mongoose.connection;
  mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

  cnx.once('open', () => {
    const gfs = Grid(cnx.db);
    app.set('gfs', gfs);
  })

  app.set('mongooseClient', mongoose);
};
```

Then add in my `/pub` service :

> pub.service.js

```
const multipartMiddleware = require('multer')();
[...]
app.use('/pub', 
      multipartMiddleware.single('uri'),
      function(req, res, next){
        req.feathers.file = req.file;
        next();
      },
      createService(options)
    );
```

> pub.hook.js

```
create: [
      hook => {
        const gfs = hook.app.get('gfs');
        const file = hook.params.file;

        console.log(hook)

        const writestream = gfs.createReadStream({
          filename: file.originalname,
          content_type: file.mimetype, // image/jpeg or image/png
        })
        const dir = __dirname;
        fs.createReadStream(`${__dirname}/img`).pipe(writestream);
      }
    ],
```

And then I get an error saying :

> MongoError: file with id ### not opened for writing

Where ### is the filename instead of the `_id`

Comment: Hey, Ragnar. Did you ever solve this? Thanks

Comment: Hey @ThomasGHenry it has been a year and yes I could solve it. The thing is I don't have access to this code base anymore. I will try to look in few days but I can't promise anything to you.

Comment: I understand. Thanks either way.